# Laurent Series in powers of $z$ and $\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm working on a few problems from my textbook and have a bit of trouble figuring out a few things.

In a particular case, suppose $R$ is a rational function all of whose poles in the plane have order one and which has no pole at the origin.

After long division: 
$R(z) = S(z) + \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$

Where $S$, $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials, and the degree of $P$ is strictly less than the degree of $Q$, concentrating on expanding $f = \frac{P}{Q}$

Then we can write: 
$f(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_k z^k$ 
 for $r <|z| < R$

Where 
$a_k = \sum_{|z_j<r|} z_j^{k-1} Res(f; z_j)$ for $k \leq -1$ 
and $= -\sum_{|z_j|>R} z_j^{-k-1} Res(f; z_j)$ for $k \geq 0$

Now for the question: 
Suppose we want to find the Laurent Series expansion for $R(z)$ in the region $|z|<1$ 
Let $R(z) = \frac{z^3 - 3z^2 + 3} {(z-1)(z-3)}$
After long division we get: 
$R(z) = (z + 1) + \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-3)}$

In this case $r = 0$, $R = 1$, so the only terms that are used are from the negative part of $a_k$ so: 
$\frac {z} {(z-1)(z-3)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k z^k$, where $a_k = - [-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{3^{k+1}}]$ for $k \geq 0$

I'm confused on how the terms for $a_k$ were found. I know the definition was given, but that's what I'm having trouble with. First off, what does $z_j$ represent? How do we find the Residue before finding the Laurent Series?

Comment: You are presumably looking for a series in powers of $z$. Since your function has no pole at $z=0$, there is no residue, your series is not merely a Laurent series but a regular power series. The specific numbers come from the Partial Fraction expansion of $z/((z-1)(z-3))$ as $-1/(2(z-1))+3/(2(z-3))$.

Comment: After doing the partial fraction decomposition, what would be the next step? I'm confused as I don't fully understand how each of the coefficients are derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for a fuller explanation than I gave in my comment. We get the following:
\begin{align}
\frac z{(z-1)(z-3)}&=\frac z{(1-z)(3-z)}\\
  &=\frac{1/2}{1-z}-\frac{3/2}{3-z}=\frac{1/2}{1-z} - \frac{1/2}{1-\frac z3}\\
  &=\frac12\Bigl(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots\Bigr)\\
  &\qquad-\frac12\Bigl(1+\frac z3+\frac{z^2}9+\frac{z^3}{27}+\cdots\Bigr)\,,
\end{align}
which should agree with your numbers.